# ::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x6b5e8a0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user and has shop models.

in user model

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :shops
 validates :shops, presence: true
end
```

and in shop model

```html
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

in user controller

```html
def show
    @shop = User.find(params[:id]).shops 

  end
```

in users/show

```html
<%= render 'user' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

 <hr color="blue">
 

 <%= @shop%>
```

```html
#<Shop::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x6b5e8a0>
```

Output comes like this . not showing the Users shop.
I want to show the shops which belongs to this user.

I can find them on the rails console by running User.find(1).shops
but not in the app

Comment: User model has **many** shops. So, which **one** user show do you want to take (in your @shop variable)??

Answer (score 0):

Since a User `has_many` Shops, you'll want to iterate over them.

```
# UserController
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# users/show
<%= render 'user' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
<hr color="blue">

<% @user.shops.each do |shop| %>
  <%= shop.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't iterating through each of the shops for the user, but rather just displaying the user in your view. So you would want something like:

```
#controller
@shops = User.find(params[:id]).shops

#view
<% @shops.each do |shop| %>
  <%= shop %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it results  #<Shop:0x5988600>

Comment: No problem. I didn't know what attrs you had for shop, so ya, just returning the @shop would just output an object, where object._____ would render that shops ______. In the case of the above question, he guessed ```name``` to fill in the blank and got it right. Glad your problem is solved!